# Linux SED replace HEX in file instead of insert? \x2A

Tags: sed, replace, hex

I have these bytes:
E6 2A 1B EF 11 00 00 00 00 00 00 4E 43 DB E8
[image]

I need to replace them with these:
64 08 1A EF 11 00 00 00 00 00 DA D8 26 04

When I started to experiment, I've noticed one strange thing.

`sed -e 's/\xE6/\x64/g'`

This code replaces first E6 with 64 ok

[image]

However when I try to change more bytes (2A) causing problem.

`sed -e 's/\xE6\x2A/\x64\x08/g'`
[image]

as I understand 2A inserts same code.. How to avoid it? I just need to change 2A with 08. Thanks in advance :)

UPDATED

---

Now I've stuck on \x26. `sed -e 's/\xDB/\x26/g'` this code refuses to replace DB to 26, but when I run `s/\xDB/\xFF` it works. Any ideas? In this way something is wrong with 26. I have tried [\x26], not helped here.

OK. `s/\xDB/\&/g'` seems to be working :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\x2a` is `*`, which is special in regex :

```
$ sed 's/a*/b/' <<<'aaa'
b
$ sed 's/a\x2a/b/' <<<'aaa'
b
```

You may use *bracket expression* in regex to cancel the special properties of characters, but I see it doesn't work well with all characters with my GNU sed:

```
$ sed 's/\xE6[\x2A]/OK/' <<<$'I am \xE6\x2A'
I am OK
$ sed 's/[\xE6][\x2A]/OK/' <<<$'I am \xE6\x2A'
I am �*
```

That's because `\xE6]` is probably some invalid UTF character. Remember to use C locale:

```
$ LC_ALL=C sed 's/[\xE6][\x2A]/OK/' <<<$'I am \xE6\x2A'
I am OK
```

Remember that `\1` `\2` etc. and `&` are special in replacement part too. Read [Escape a string for a sed replace pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern) - but you will need to escape `\xXX` sequences instead of each character (or convert characters to the actual bytes first, why work with all the `\xXX` sequences?). Or pick another tool.

Comment: now I've stuck on \x26. `sed -e 's/\xDB/\x26/g'` this code refuses to replace DB to 26, but when I run `s/\xDB/\xFF` it works. Any ideas?

Comment: `Remember that \1 \2 etc. and & are special in replacement part too` - did you? And read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern - did you?